# Extracting substring with regex with optional prefix

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, re2, looker-studio

I'm working with strings (Campaign names) that either take this format:

```
#serial => text
```

Or are without the first part:

```
text
```

I'm trying to use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` to extract the text part only. This one works great for the first kind:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campaign, '.* => (.*)')
```

But I'm having problems making the "`#serial =>`" part optional. I'm working within Google Data Studio, so these are RE2-style regular expressions and I'm limited to `REGEXP_EXTRACT`, `REGEXP_MATCH` and `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm doing this within Google Data Studio, so I'm bound to RE2-style regular expressions and the following functions: REGEXP_EXTRACT, REGEXP_MATCH and REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: How about this pattern `^(.*=>\s)?(.*)`

Comment: Also, I don't know google data studio but if use `REGEXP_REPLACE` and replace `.*=> ` with empty string, probably you should get always `text part only`

Comment: Oto, you are my new favourite person in the world. Your suggestion worked perfectly: REGEXP_REPLACE(Campaign, '.* => ', ''). გმადლობთ!

Comment: @Ragnar - You are welcome ))

Answer (score 0):

[Oto Shavadze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771033/extracting-substring-with-regex-with-optional-prefix#comment78500729_45771033) came up with this simple but elegant solution to the problem:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Campaign, '.* => ', '')
```